# 16.04 Stuck at login (amd radeon gpu) tried all the methods

Tags: boot, 16.04, login

First, my system works fine as 16.04 version for 2 months now, and it suddenly stuck at the login loop yesterday.

I already tried the following methods

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup
```

after reboot, nothing happens. Then, `ls -ld /tmp` output

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 28 21:05 /tmp
```

after this, I see `.xsession-errors` and `.xsession-errors.old`, no output.

then,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

still not working, then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session ubuntu-desktop
```

I even created new user `sudo adduser newguest`, still not a chance.

also, I tried to install new desktop environment

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo reboot
```

still not working...

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, it was because my system partition was full. Removing around 150 MB didn't do the trick, so I made the partition bigger with the live USB stick.